PySpark on Dataproc out of memory
I am trying to load 1.5 million rows with into a BigQuery table using PySpark:
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('process-prices') \
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "80g") \
    .config("spark.memory.offHeap.size", "16g") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "16g") \
    .getOrCreate()

But I am getting this error:
[2024-04-02 07:21:29.617]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 52. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** occurred dispatching signal SIGTERM to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated

I tried changing the properties:

spark.executor.memoryOverhead
spark.memory.offHeap.size
spark.executor.memory

If I reduce the amount of lines, it works fine, like
    df = df.limit(50)
    print("Trying to write to BQ")
    df.write.format("bigquery") \
        .option("table", "x.y.z") \
        .save()

So it is indeed a problem with the large dataset.
What can I do to stream the data in batches? I think this would be a solution.
I am new to Spark so I don't know how to tune it yet.
